# making search term visable as label on search result page

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my search page.
I need the referencenumber to be visible in the search result page, when I search for a referencenumber. (OrderNumber)

How to use the input id to display this as a label or something like that?

```
<div class="input-group referenceInput">
    <input id="referenceNumber" class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="referenceNumber" required name="referenceNumber">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="getByRefNum()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyph-m-r"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: How about just adding `{{ referenceNumber }}`? Where is the search result page? How is it displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you will have separate result page, and reference number will be passed to API as request params. You can pass this reference number to result page in URL params.
Once, the result is fetched, you can pick the reference number either from API response or URL params and access it in your view using `{{ referenceNumber }}`. Display it in HTML wherever you like by applying required CSS classes.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work by adding this to page:

        <h2>Ordernr: {{model.referenceNumber}}</h2>

Comment: Upvoting answer is a nice way of showing appreciation!